# Putting AND or OR in one condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have an `EMPLOYEE` table which returns an `EMPLOYEE_type`. The value of `EMPLOYEE_type` can be 1 or 2 .

I have another table `DISCOUNT` in which we have column `DISCOUNT_EMPLOYEE_TYPE`. The value of `DISCOUNT_EMPLOYEE_TYPE` can be 1, 2 or NULL (not present).

I have to find the below result.

1. if `EMPLOYEE_type = 2` then show all the `DISCOUNT` with  `DISCOUNT_EMPLOYEE_TYPE = 2`.
2. if `EMPLOYEE_type = 1` then show all the `DISCOUNT` with  `DISCOUNT_EMPLOYEE_TYPE = 1` or NULL.

I have tried below query so far :

```
DECLARE @employee_type smallint 

SET @employee_type = (SELECT employee_type FROM [dbo].[EMPLOYEE] (nolock)
                AND employee_stub = @employee_stub)

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DISCOUNT] (nolock)
WHERE acct_id = @acct_id 
  AND (discount_employee_type = @employee_type
       OR (@employee_type IS NULL AND @employee_type = 1))
```

It is returning the correct result if `@employee_type = 2`.

However, it is not returning NULL values in case of `@employee_type = 1` - I only get back rows with `discount_employee_type = 1` .

Comment: `= null`?  That will never return true.  You want `is null`.

Comment: I have tried wilh `is null` as well , it did not give the result yet

Comment: Actually `(@employee_type is null and @employee_type=1)` will never be successful

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK` against both of your tables? Are you happy with potentially erroneous data?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, based on your description, that the WHERE clause should be

```
WHERE
acct_id = @acct_id 
and (
    (employee_type = 2 AND discount_employee_type = 2)
    OR (@employee_type = 1 AND (discount_employee_type = 1 OR discount_employee_type IS NULL))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE expression in the WHERE clause to check each of the 2 conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DISCOUNT] 
WHERE acct_id = @acct_id
AND 1 = CASE
  WHEN @employee_type = 1 AND COALESCE(discount_employee_type, 1) = 1 THEN 1
  WHEN @employee_type = 2 AND discount_employee_type = 2 THEN 1 
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Corrected my code:

```
declare @employee_type int
declare @discount table
(
col1 int
,discount_employee_type varchar(1)
)

--set @employee_type = 1
set @employee_type = 2

insert into @discount(col1,discount_employee_type)
values (1,'1'), (2,'1'), (3,'2'), (4,null), (5,'2')

select * from @discount

select * 
from
@discount

WHERE

1 = 

CASE 
    WHEN @employee_type = 1 and (discount_employee_type is null or discount_employee_type = 1) then 1
    WHEN @employee_type =  2 and  discount_employee_type = 2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

[DBFiddle link here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=921b291ba0793d48d2ee7e0bc738e454)